# Find the number of rotations in a cyclic sequence

Tags: c, algorithm

I have been given two arrays by user. My code should find out how many rotations it had either to left or right . We can safely assume that elements don't repeat.

i/p:

array (arr1)           2, 6, 4, 10, 8 ,12 ,11

rotated array(arr2)     4, 10, 8, 12, 11, 2, 6

o/p: 2

Method1:

My approach to this problem would be like this:

1.Take first element from rotated array and also take the last element from rotated array. Name them "first" and "last" respectively. And also initialize the count to 0

2.Start comparing "first" with elements of arr1 from the beginning , until we reach the number "first" in arr1. At the same time start comparing "last" with elements of arr1 from the end  and keep decrementing until we reach the number equivalent to "last" in arr1.

3.We can do increment and decrement for the step 2 above in the same for loop for step2.And also increment count variable.

3.Thats it, whichever of "first" or "last" finds its equivalent early then break and print the count.

Method2:

Take first element of the arr2 and start comparing it with arr1 elements from the end , and do it until we find a match. The number of times we decremented the arr1 is equivalent to the number of rotations

Is there any better approach then above two ?

Comment: What if a number repeated?

Comment: At first blush, I would maintain an index for each array and start them both at the beginning of each array. (NOTE it's possible that the second array was shifted zero positions, so it's good to check for that.) Then set up a loop that goes the length of the array, comparing each element at each of the indices. If you hit a mismatch before you get to the end of the loop, then increment the second index only and start the loop over. In the comparison in the loop, make it a "wrap around" comparison (if you're at element `11` in a 10-element array, then it wraps to the first element).

Comment: Double the size of the first array, and duplicate it. Loop through it and every time you find a `4`, compare the next `n-1` elements for a match. Store how many steps you had to make to find the `4`. If you know there are no duplicates, then just stop when you've found the `4`. Wrapping around instead of duplicating gets the same result in slightly more complicated code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you "can safely assume that elements don't repeat", then there is no better way than stepping through the elements of `arr1` until you've found the first element of `arr2`. The number of steps you had to make is your left rotation. You can calculate the right rotation by subtracting the left rotation from the length of either array and subtracting 1.

Comment: Even if there are duplicates @Paul Griffiths approach will help us.